# Phalcon doesnt work properly on nginx

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx, docker, phalcon

Today I have a problem with **Phalcon** (2.0.7).

Main environment is running **Centos 7** which runs docker with Debian's latest image. On Docker I have installed **PHP 5.4.45** and **Nginx 1.2.1**

There is config file (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)

```
user    www-data www-data;  ## Default: nobody
worker_processes 5;  ## Default: 1
error_log   logs/error.log;
#pid    logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
worker_connections 4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    #   include /etc/nginx/proxy_conf;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
        '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  logs/access.log main;
    sendfile    on;
    tcp_nopush  on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts

    server {
        server_name 149.202.61.223;
        listen 80;

        #    access_log /srv/www/example.com/log/access.log;
        #    error_log /srv/www/example.com/log/error.log;

        root /var/www/vokuro/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @php_mvc;
        }

        location @php_mvc {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 last;
        }

        location ~ ^(.+\.php)(/.*)?$ {
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)?$;

             set $script_filename $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

             if (!-e $script_filename) {
                 return 404;
             }

             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_index index.php;
             include fastcgi_params;

             fastcgi_param   APPLICATION_ENV development;
             fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $script_filename;
             fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
             fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
       }
    }   
}
```

I've cloned https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro project to

```
/var/www/vokuro
```

and it has files as

```
CONTRIBUTING.md  README.md  app  composer.json  index.html  public  schemas
```

So everything above looks corretly I suppose but it isn't working. Error reporting is on but it shows nothing.

**Do anyone of you know where I have done a mistake? What's wrong with that?**

PS. The configuration I wrote is running on http://149.202.61.223/ you can check it but there is only a blank page.

PS1. PHP is working fine i can do phpinfo or anything else

PS2. Phalcon is recognizing by php/nginx too (I have checked it)

Comment: it seems that you fixed the problem. so please write your solution.

Comment: Probably that was problem with database connection. Phalcon didn't print any stacktrace or error. Anyway I did some changes and it started to work.

Comment: For stacktrace or error reporting you must use [Pretty Exceptions](https://github.com/phalcon/pretty-exceptions) library.